# Determine whether two collections of items can be paired

Tags: algorithms, matching, bipartite-matching

Given collections `I` (items) and `S` (slots), where `I >= S`.
And a pairing function that determines whether a slot can accept an item.

Is there an efficient way to find whether a "complete" pairing of items to slots exist, where "complete" means every slot is filled?

(More importantly for my use case... is there a way, other than trying every combination, to determine if no such pairing exists?)

Comment: Hall's Marriage Theorem comes to mind.

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret It does, but that's a very inefficient test as you have exponentially many sets to check. It's much more efficient to just construct a maximum-cardinality matching and see if it covers everything you need to cover, since that can be done in polynomial time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You're just looking for a maximum [matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)) in the bipartite graph where one side is the items, the other side is the slots and there's an edge between an item and each slot it's compatible with.

There are a number of efficient [algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#Algorithms_and_computational_complexity) for this. The standard method taught to CS undergraduates is the [augmenting paths algorithm of Hopcroft and Karp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm).

Comment: Perfect! There's even an existing implementation in the language I'm using.

Comment: @AdamMichaelWood Awesome!